# php array key issue with foreach loop and multi-dim arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have listed an example below.  What I need is for $key to return the actual index number (position) in the array during the loop, but instead it is returning Array.  The same code works fine when given a single dimension array, but not in the example below.

**GIVEN:**

$screenshots would be similar to the following with only more entries.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [screenshot_id] => 871
            [image_filename] => DSCF0124.JPG
        )

)
```

**PHP:**

```
//build in clause & binding using selected array from above
$prefix = $in_clause = '';
$binding_clause = array();  
foreach($screenshots as $key)
{
    $in_clause .= $prefix.':selected_'.$key;
    $prefix = ', ';
    $binding_clause[':selected_'.$key] = $key['screenshot_id'];
}
```

**RESULT:**

```
$inclause = :selected_Array

$binding_clause = 

Array
(
    [:selected_Array] => 871
)
```

**EXPECTED:**

```
$inclause = :selected_0

$binding_clause = 

Array
(
    [:selected_0] => 871
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you call it `$key` doesn't make it a key.  You need the key and the value (inner array):

```
foreach($screenshots as $key => $value)
{
    $in_clause .= $prefix.':selected_'.$key;
    $prefix = ', ';
    $binding_clause[':selected_'.$key] = $value['screenshot_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it that you want the KEY and the VALUE.

like this:

```
foreach($screenshots as $key=>$screenShot)
```

That will get you the key and the value.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your foreach to cast keys and values

```
foreach($screenshots as $key => $val)
```

Now the key is in your `$key` variable while you can access elements with `$val` array, for example `$key['screenshot_id']`

You can have a check to documentation examples [**here**](http://php.net/manual/it/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
foreach($screenshots as $key => $screenshot)
{
    $in_clause .= $prefix.':selected_'.$key;
    $prefix = ', ';
    $binding_clause[':selected_'.$key] = $screenshot['screenshot_id'];
}
```

Read more about PHP foreach: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php